# Checking for substring match in django template

Tags: django, django-templates

In my template I have:

```
{% if form.non_field_errors %}
<div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">
  {% if "already exists" in form.non_field_errors %}
    You've already submitted your request once. Please wait for confirmation, or email us at support@relsoft.in
  {% else %}
    {{ form.non_field_errors }}
  {% endif %}
</div>
{% endif %}
```

It seems that the `{% if "already exists" in form.non_field_errors %}` block isnt working. I'm getting the following in the output:

```
<div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">      
  <ul class="errorlist nonfield"><li>Pendingclinics with this Name, Mobile and Email already exists.</li></ul>   
</div>
```

Comment: This is really the wrong approach. You should define a custom `clean()` method on your form and raise your specific error there.

Comment: Actually @DanielRoseman is correct!

Comment: Do you need a custom clear method unless you need specific additional relationships between data? This error is because unique_together is set in the model

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before going into this answer, please note the comment of @DanielRoseman above: This is really the wrong approach. You should define a custom clean() method on your form and raise your specific error there.

So although the code below answers your question, but it is NOT best practice!

`form.non_field_errors` is a list. When you say

```
if s in form.non_field_errors
```

this means that you are checking whether `form.non_field_errors` contains an element exactly equal to s. This is not the case in your code. Your `form.non_field_errors` contains an element (a string) that itself contains the substring "already exists".

You want to go over the errors and check whether one of them contains this substring. This seems like me to the kind of logic you want to do in the view, not the template. For example, in the view:

```
was_submitted_before = any(["already exists" in s for s in form.non_field_errors])
```

You can then pass the `was_submitted_before` variable to your template, and in the template you can test whether this is true.

Comment: Or maybe a `{% for %}` loop in the template, and then an `{% if substr in string %}`?

Comment: @Droidzone you can do that too; it seems like you are putting application logic in the template though and that is not the best practice.

Comment: @Droidzone the problem with that is also, how do you tell if the substring was *not* in any of the strings?

Comment: @Dave You're spot  on. I discovered that just now

Answer (score 1):

`form.non_field_errors` is a list of strings, not a single string.

So you're asking if `'already exists'` is in `['Pendingclinics with this Name, Mobile and Email already exists.']`, which is `false`.

You'll have to do something a little more complex to check if that particular error exists, I'm afraid.